# What does it mean that $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have recently read that

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)=\cos(x)$$

But,unfortunately I have not been able to make out what it exactly means that the rate of change of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$?

What does it simply mean that rate of change of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$?

I am a beginner in this branch of mathematics.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Context would be nice. Have you learned any calculus? Are you comfortable, for example, with the claim that $\frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x$, or *any* claim involving $\frac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: To get a visual idea, you might want to look at the graphs of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, and compare the slope of the tangents to $\sin x$ graph with the value of $\cos x$, especially at points $x = \frac{n\pi}{2}$.

Comment: You have it exactly right, the rate of change of sin(x) is indeed cos(x).

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but I wonder if the original poster would also appreciate a link a good set of introductory calculus notes. A more in depth discussion would be more likely to give understanding in this case.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I'm not convinced this question is a duplicate of the cited question.  It's plausible to me that pjs36's question is on point: that the OP is seeking to understand how the derivative of $\sin x$ is some other function.  (To many students, it seems to answer one question with another.)  More context is needed, to be sure; I might well have voted to put the question on hold for that reason.

Comment: @tatan: In fact, the derivative—which in this case you may rightly view as a rate of change—of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$.  That is to say, the rate of change of $\sin x$ at $x = 0$ is $1$, which happens to be $\cos 0$.  The rate of change of $\sin x$ at $x = \pi/4$ at $x = 0$ is $\sqrt{2}{2}$, which happens to be $\cos \pi/4$; the rate of change at $x = \pi/3$ is $1/2$, which happens to be $\cos \pi/3$; and in general, the rate of change at $x = x_0$ is whatever $\cos x_0$ happens to be.  (Of course, calculus shows that there's nothing "happens to be" about it—that this is the rule.)

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that the slope of the line tangent to the graph of $\sin(x)$ at a point $(x_0, \sin(x_0))$ is equal to $\cos(x_0)$.